# Is it possible for the set of critical points of a differentiable function $f$ to be union of the diagonal lines defined by $y= \pm x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

Let  $f: \mathbb{R}^2 ⟶ \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Let $S$ denote the set of critical points of $f$. Is it possible for $S$ to be the union of $y = x$ and $y = -x$? I recently stumbled upon a textbook question asking if $S$ could be the union of the $x$ and $y$ axes, which led me to wonder about $y= \pm x$.

The way I thought about the question was that the partials with respect to $x$ and $y$ must be $0$ for this to occur. Hence, $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$$

Moreover, these partials can only be $0$ when $y = x$ **or** $y = -x$. This "or" is the part where I get confused - my original thought was for the partials to be $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = x - y, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = x + y$$ But this leads to an intersection, not a union.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: were you able to answer original question from the textbook?

Comment: Yes, I was! It seems my train of thought for this question wasn't saved in the post somehow - please see my edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, both problems are equivalent: If a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is critical at the diagonals $y=\pm x$, then you may just rotate the $x$-$y$-plane by 45$^\circ$ using a coordinate transformation
$$\Phi(x,y) = \left(\frac{x+y}{2},\frac{x-y}{2}\right)$$
So the function $f\circ \Phi$ is critical at the union of the $x$- and the $y$-axis.

Conversely, if $f$ is critical on these two axes then $f \circ \Phi$ is critical at the diagonals.

Now, the function
$$f(x,y) = x^2 y^2$$
is critical exactly at $ \{(x,y) \mid x=0 \lor y=0\} $, i.e. the union of both coordinate axes. You may check this by taking the two derivatives $\partial_x f(x,y)=2xy^2$ and $\partial_y f(x,y)=2x^2 y$, which get both zero if either $x=0$ or $y=0$ (or both). Correspondingly,
$$ (f \circ \Phi)(x,y)=\left( \frac{x+y}{2} \right)^2 \left( \frac{x-y}{2} \right)^2 $$
is critical on the union of both diagonals.